# how to Flush Crawl Database?

Tags: sharepoint-server

SharePoint Search_Crawl_483487384  Database is growing unexpectedly.

How this database can be flushed in order to re build all crawls?

Answer (score 3):

To empty out the entire Crawl database in SharePoint 2010, you'd go to Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Service Applications > Search Service Application, then when you're looking at the page that has Crawl status, there's a link on the left for "Index Reset." When you do this, it's going to suspend search alerts and rip thru that database. Once it's finished, all users will get ZERO search results until you complete new crawls.
Now you need to run the FUll Crawl.

But if you are crawling a lot of content it will be grow again. Also check the below blog for some guidelines.

http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/is-your-search-database-bloated

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8217.sharepoint-2010-manage-the-crawl-database-size.aspx